# BASH open file from variable: The file <xxx> does not exist

Tags: bash, macos

### Description of Task & problem

I have dumped a list of files which match certain criteria to a text file.  The command i used is:

`find . -name "*.logic" | grep -v  '.bak' | grep -v 'Project File Backup' > logic_manifest.txt`

Filenames with spaces in are proving difficult to automatically open, such as :

`./20160314 _ Pop/20160314 _ Pop.logic`

I have replaced the spaces with '\ ' to escape them but the open command complains:

> The file /Users/daniel/Music/Logic/20160314\ _\ Pop/20160314\ _\ Pop.logic does not exist.

When I copy that parsed path, type open in the terminal and paste it in, the file opens successfully.

### My BASH script:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

# file full of file paths, gathered using the find command
#logic_manifest.txt

# For keeping track of which line of the file I'm using
COUNTER=0
it=1

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do

  # Increment iterator
  COUNTER=`expr $COUNTER + $it`

  # replace spaces with a black-slash and space
  line=${line// /<>}
  line=${line//<>/'\ '} 

  # print the file name and the line it is on
  echo "Line: $COUNTER $line" 

  #open the file
  open "$line"

  # await key press before moving on to next iterator
  read input </dev/tty
done < "$1"
```

Encapsulating the filename in speech-marks has not helped

```
  line=${line// /<>}
  line=${line//<>/'\ '} 
  line="\"$line\""
```

> The file /Users/daniel/Music/Logic/"./20160314\ _\ Pop/20160314\ _\
>   Pop.logic" does not exist.

Nor did passing `"\${line}"` to `open`

### Question

What do I need to do to enable the open command to launch the files successfully?

- Renaming the directories and filenames is not a viable option at this time.
- Spaces in filenames are bad, I know, I put it down to moments of madness

Comment: Why would just `open "$line"` not work?  Enclosing the variable in double quotes would protect the spaces.  No need for encapsulating as you are doing currently.

Comment: Furthermore, the `find` command should look like this: `find . -name "*.logic" -a  ! -name '*.bak' -a ! -name 'Project File Backup' -print0 > logic_manifest.txt`. Then in the script which reads the file use `$'\0'` - a null byte - as the field delimiter.

Comment: @codeforester I don't know why it's not working with that invocation, it returns the error 
`The file /Users/daniel/Music/Logic/20160314 _\ Pop/20160314 _\ Pop.logic does not exist.`

Comment: You do not need to do any manipulation of the filename: `while IFS= read -r filename; do if [[ -f "$filename" ]]; then echo "line: $((++counter)) $filename"; open "$filename"; fi; done < "$1"`

Comment: Usability hint: add a prompt to that read command: `read -p "Hit enter..." x`

Comment: @hek2mgl Thanks, but the find command I used lists the files and excludes certain directories.  I just tried the command you supplied and it did not exclude the directories

Comment: Then it should be `-a ! -path '*.bak'` and so on. `-name` -> `-path`

Comment: @glennjackman, Thanks but none of the files are seen by that condition `[[ ]]`

Comment: @hek2mgl Thanks, but that still fails to omit the undesired entries.  I had a lot of trouble getting that to work which is why it's grep'ed

Comment: In your script, do you actually have this line: `logic_manifest.txt` ?? Are you trying to execute that file as a program?

Comment: @glennjackman no it's passed when invoking this script `./manifest_run.txt logic_manifest.txt`

Comment: yes, I assumed that. But what is the 2nd non-comment line in the script you posted?

Comment: Updated the second, non comment line to be a comment. It exists as information only. Typo when writing the script to this post. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is absolutely no need whatsoever to replace any characters in `line`.
This simpler loop should open files just fine:

```
while IFS='' read -r line; do
  ((COUNTER++))

  echo "Line: $COUNTER $line" 

  open "$line"

  read input </dev/tty
done < "$1"
```

That's it. Moreover:

> Spaces in filenames are bad, I know, I put it down to moments of madness.

There's nothing wrong with spaces in filenames.
You just have to use proper quoting, that's all.

That is, if the file names didn't have spaces and other special characters in them, then you could write `open $line` and it would work.
Since they contain spaces, you must enclose the variable in double-quotes, as in `open "$line"`.
Actually it's strongly recommended to enclose variables in double-quotes when used in command line arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it returns the same error message

Comment: Please use the exact error message, and also, the filename that causes problem. Paste it precisely as it looks in the input file.

Comment: That's odd. It didn't work 30 minutes ago but it does now. Both times I copied and pasted it directly... Thank you